# Close another form to C#

Tags: c#, coding-style

I have 2 windows form, 1 login form and 1 main form. I want to close main form and login form together. How can i do?

I tryed this command;

```
Form2 ac = new Form2();
ac.Show();
this.Close();
```

but this closing all forms. I want only close `Form1`.

Comment: First you say you want to close the main form and login form together, then you said you only want to close Form1 (but the code says Form2).  The question is very unclear.

Comment: @AhmedMasud i writing this code to Form1_Load

Comment: @Sirchade please show entire routine

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey my english not very good, sorry. :)

Comment: @Sirchade -  Provide more relevant code.  We have a better chance of figuring out your needs with the language barrier.

Comment: @Sirchade do you want to close login form or main form or both ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Main method contains:

```
  Application.Run(form1);
```

And you are closing `form1`, your application closes.

You could "temporary" hide the form1 while displaying the ac. Use ShowDialog, to block your code until the ac form is closed:

```
   using (Form2 ac = new Form2()) {
     this.Hide();
     if (ac.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
       this.Show();
     } else {
      // Exit app
       this.Close();   
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you close the main form of course all the windows will close, the main form contains all other 
forms, your Q is not clear, can you give us a clear snippet that will show what you want to do?

Comment: First form1 coming and form2(visible=false), they writing username and password, pressing enter and going to form2(visible=true now). (now i want close form1) –

Comment: is the form1 your main form? 
edit:
i think i got you... ( hope so ) i think you mixed your main form with subforms your main form is where you type in user name and password and your subform is where you want to continue with right?

Comment: Form1 = Loginform
Form2= Mainform

Comment: look in Program.cs for the line 'Application.Run(new Form1());'
which form is in it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which form is calling which other form (and how), you have to somehow "bubble" the request to close from within the login form to the main form.

Suppose that form 1 calls form 2 modally:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // ...

    private void callForm2()
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        if ( form2.ShowDialog( this )== DialogResult.Abort )
        {
            // Close myself if called form instructs me to close.
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, I used the `DialogResult.Abort` as the "communication signal" to close. This could be done in `Form2` like the following:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    // ...

    private void buttonCloseAll_Click( object sender, EventArgs args )
    {
        // Close myself _and_ return the abort result to the caller.
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort;
    }
}
```

Please note that this is just an (uncomplete example). I'm sure there are alternative solutions to your requirement.

Comment: First form1 coming and form2(visible=false), they writing username and password, pressing enter and going to form2(visible=true now). (now i want close form1)

Comment: sorry but, doesnt work. Im opened now google translator.

I want to completely shut down in form1 from form2 to form1 in transition.

Answer (score 0):

The 1. form you open is the main form for the application. This has nothing to do how you name your forms or what is on this forms. If you close the main form your application terminates.

You could do this two things in your situation:

1. hide your login form instead of closing it
2. open your main form first and use your login form as a modal dialog on top of it. In this case you can close the login form and your applications continuous to run.